# Monitor suddently stopped displaying

Tags: graphics-card, vga, dvi

suddently my monitor stopped displaying. I'm not sure what happened, just poof it stopped receiving signal.

Here's what I tried:
I tried to move video card from one PCI slot to another
I tried to test monitor with laptop - it works with a laptop

Graphics card seems to be functioning properly, it's power led is green and it spins the fan normally. It's an AMD card.

I have a tiny problem, I use one of these DVI to VGA adapters http://corel.force.com/index/servlet/rtaImage?eid=ka060000000PKlG&feoid=00N600000028y5z&refid=0EM60000000L5OP since my graphics card has only one DVI adapter and no VGA.

So, I want to ask, how often these little at first glance insignificant parts like DVI to VGA adapter break? Because it seems counter intuitive, I never had video card break. This seems the only reasonable option for that small part to go bust.

But how should I check that? How would I test if my graphics card is functioning properly? I don't want to waste money to buy DVI cable (even though it is cheap) and I certainly don't want to buy a new card.

Comment: Do you have another monitor you can connect the computer to? Do you have another computer you can connect to your monitor?

Comment: Not at the moment, no

Comment: If you can get the event log open before the monitor dies, read that, or get something like teamviewer and remote into it from another computer or your phone. Teamviewer doesn't care if there's a display connected :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is more plausible that your graphics card has failed than a passive DVI -> VGA adapter, as these have no active components to actually fail. Beyond bent pins, it is highly unlikely, and unless you frequently unplug/replug the adapter I wouldn't expect this to be the case. As you have tested the monitor on another machine without a problem, I would suspect your card.

Be aware that just because the fan and LED work on the card, this is only really indicative that the card is receiving power, not that it is in any way functional.

In terms of testing further, you can:

1. Try another monitor on the same graphics card,
2. Try your current monitor on your motherboards graphics, if present,
3. Try another graphics card in the machine.
4. Try your graphics card in another machine to confirm the functionality of the card.

From your information so far, I suspect the graphics card would be at fault.